# How to enable php debug messages only for my ip?

Tags: php

I am experimenting with `php` on an `apache` server for the learning experience. Being relucant to setup production and development server, I was guided that `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` should be used to [enable warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

I would like to enable debug messages only when accessing the apache server from a specific IP: my external IP. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10):

I assume you refer to php runtime errors as debug messages. You can accomplish that in PHP app. you can change error reporting in runtime. all you need is to add these line in your PHP app.

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your_ip_address') {  
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);  
}
```

Another way to collect more detailed information about runtime in PHP is [ChromePHP](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp)

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) they describe that enabling errors at run-time is useless, because if the script crashes (e.g. syntax error), no nothing will be displayed. That is why `php.ini` needs to be used. I could have misunderstood. Please explain.

Comment: Yes it's a very common pitfall for PHP and that's the reason why we use/need error_reporting. It's there to fix it back as you can understand it's an error itself in first place fault)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'ip address') {  
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
}
```

Although there are many ways to display errors and warnings in PHP. See this.

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Comment: Please see my follow-up question under `risyasin`'s answer.